# erroneous result of access(...) call on encfs mounted path

Tags: permissions, debian, fuse

I'm running debian testing, `kernel 4.1.1`, `glibc version 2.19-20`.
When I perform `access( ..., X_OK )` on **any file** which is mounted by `encfs` (version `1.8.1-3+b1`), it returns `0` (meaning its an executable).
However, performing a `stat(...)` on the same file, `.st_mode` shows me that it's not an executable (which is the correct result).

Is this an issue with `access(...)` or `encfs`. What could be the possible reasons for this erroneous output of `access(...)`

Comment: I did download and install encfs 1.8.2, but that does not solve the issue. I am beginning to believe that the problem might be with `libfuse2 (2.9.4-1)`

Comment: https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/v1.8.1/encfs/main.cpp#L601 encfs should give you a ENOSYS result for the access system call.